# ng-repeat select the initial value in the list

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Please help with ng-repeat. I created a list of values ​​using ng-repeat. 
How can I specify the value of the middle of the list that I want to show first (I want to show 'Earth' first in the list)? My code:

html

```
<li class="list__item" ng-repeat="poster in posters">{{poster.title}}</li>
```

controller:

```
'use strict';
 angular.module('oldmenTest')
  .controller('FormController', ['$scope', 'postersName', function($scope, postersName) {
  $scope.posters= postersName.getPosters();

}]);
```

vars:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('oldmenTest')
.service('postersName', function() {

var posters = [{
    title: 'Mars',
    description: 'NASA\'s Mars Exploration Program seeks to understand whether Mars was, is, or can be a habitable world. Mission like Mars Pathfinder, Mars Exploration Rovers, Mars Science Laboratory and Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter, among many others, have provided important information in understanding of the habitability of Mars. This poster imagines a future day when we have achieved our vision of human exploration of Mars and takes a nostalgic look back at the great imagined milestones of Mars exploration that will someday be celebrated as “historic sites.”',
    image: '/images/mars.jpg'
}, {
    title: 'Earth',
    description: 'There\'s no place like home. Warm, wet and with an atmosphere that\'s just right, Earth is the only place we know of with life – and lots of it. JPL\'s Earth science missions monitor our home planet and how it\'s changing so it can continue to provide a safe haven as we reach deeper into the cosmos.',
    image: '/images/earth.jpg'
}
];

this.getPosters = function(){
    return posters;
};

});
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: keep earth on 1st index in your poster var

Comment: the order can not be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its just workaround, but it will work..

```js
angular.module('app', [])
      .controller('Controller', function($scope) {
       
$scope.posters = [{
    title: 'Mars',
    description: 'NASA\'s Mars Exploration Program seeks to understand whether Mars was, is, or can be a habitable world. Mission like Mars Pathfinder, Mars Exploration Rovers, Mars Science Laboratory and Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter, among many others, have provided important information in understanding of the habitability of Mars. This poster imagines a future day when we have achieved our vision of human exploration of Mars and takes a nostalgic look back at the great imagined milestones of Mars exploration that will someday be celebrated as “historic sites.”',
    image: '/images/mars.jpg'
}, {
    title: 'Earth',
    description: 'There\'s no place like home. Warm, wet and with an atmosphere that\'s just right, Earth is the only place we know of with life – and lots of it. JPL\'s Earth science missions monitor our home planet and how it\'s changing so it can continue to provide a safe haven as we reach deeper into the cosmos.',
    image: '/images/earth.jpg'
}, {
    title: 'Jupiter',
    description: 'There\'s no place like home. Warm, wet and with an atmosphere that\'s just right, Earth is the only place we know of with life – and lots of it. JPL\'s Earth science missions monitor our home planet and how it\'s changing so it can continue to provide a safe haven as we reach deeper into the cosmos.',
    image: '/images/jupiter.jpg'
}
];
      })
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <li class="list__item" ng-if="poster.title=='Earth'" ng-repeat="poster in posters">{{poster.title}}</li>
    <li class="list__item"  ng-if="poster.title!='Earth'" ng-repeat="poster in posters">{{poster.title}}</li>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```