# condition for ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angular-ng-if

Help me please with ng-model. I have an input field where when selecting substituted values from an array 'posters'. Yhe value selected by the filter appear in the list. The list is displayed by default 'The grund tour'. When I enter in the form of a value that is not in the array - in the list displays an empty field, but I need to be displayed or the value of the array or the default value (if the form is entered the value is not of the array). I have no idea how to do it. 
I think it may be possible to apply for a condition for the ng-model to make it work only for the values of an array

My code html:

```
<div class="container" ng-controller = "FormController">
    <div class="container__item container__form"><!-- 1 -->
        <form action="" class="form">
            <input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="on" list="posters" ng-model="posterTitle"  >
            <datalist id="posters" >
                <option ng-repeat="poster in posters" >{{poster.title}}
                </option>
            </datalist> 
        </form>         
    </div>
    <div class="container__item container__list"><!-- 2 --> 
        <ul class="list" id="item">
            <li class="list__item" ng-if="poster.title =='The grand tour'" ng-repeat="poster in posters | filter:posterTitle"><i class="fa fa-rocket list__fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{poster.title}}</li>
            <li class="list__item" ng-if="poster.title!='The grand tour'" ng-repeat="poster in posters | filter:{title:posterTitle}">{{poster.title}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Controller:

```
'use strict';
  angular.module('oldmenTest')
   .controller('FormController', ['$scope', 'postersName', function($scope, postersName) {
    $scope.posters= postersName.getPosters();

    $scope.posterTitle = '';
 }]);
```

Var:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('oldmenTest')
 .service('postersName', function() {

var posters = [{
    title: 'var1',
    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
    image: 'resources/images/mars.jpg'
}, {
    title: 'var2',
    description: 'TLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
    image: 'resources/images/earth.jpg'
}, {
    title: 'var3',
    description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.',
    image: 'resources/images/venus.jpg'
}
];

this.getPosters = function(){
    return posters;
};

});
```

Thanks for hepl!

Comment: Not at all clear what you are asking. Try editing question with a more complete explanation of what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: If I enter into a form field, connotation selected from the array and is inserted in the list box (<ul>). Now, if I enter a value that does not exist in the array, the list displays an empty field. I need to get it displayed the default value to the form field was without ng-model.

Comment: Still not clear. Are you trying to add to the array? Again, update question with a clear, concise and properly detailed explanation of the problem

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have to apply filter conditionally on specific property or all properties based on title.

You could do something like below.

```
<li class="list__item" 
 ng-init="poster.filter = (poster.title =='The grand tour' ? {filter: posterTitle }: posterTitle" 
 ng-repeat="poster in posters | filter: poster.filter">
      <i ng-if="poster.title =='The grand tour'" class="fa fa-rocket list__fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>.
      {{poster.title}}
 </li>
```

Comment: my code: `<li class="list__item" ng-init="poster.filter = (posterTitle == poster.title ? {filter: posterTitle }: posterTitle" ng-if="poster.title =='The grand tour'"  ng-repeat="poster in posters | filter:{title:posterTitle}"><i class="fa fa-rocket list__fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{poster.title}}</li><li class="list__item">`  It Error  in console

Comment: Don't use `ng-if`

Comment: Check updated, you don't need to have to li with ng-if, you could use this as single li

Comment: I need two li because first I have to bring the value of the middle of the array. In this question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40437809/ng-repeat-select-the-initial-value-in-the-list/40438138#40438138) suggested solution.  In this case, I need to leave all values of the array in the list if the form is entered a value that does not correspond to the array